# Reference request: an elementary proof of Brouwer fixed-point theorem.

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

One of the elementary way to prove of the Brouwer fixed-point theorem is,  making it follow from the (smooth) Non-Retraction theorem. The latter is then proven by contradiction by means of a simple computation on the "oriented area" of smooth mappings $g:B\subset \mathbb {R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb {R}^n$
$$\int_B \operatorname{det} D g(x) dx$$

and only involves a differentiation under the sign of integral with respect to the parameter of deformation (I mentioned this proof in [this wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_using_the_oriented_area)) . Due to this fact, I sometimes like to use it in elementary courses as a meaningful application of differential calculus and Lebesgue integration (on the other hand, the geometrical ideas behind remain a bit hidden, but that is an other story).

However, a slight annoyance to me now is, that I can't remember where I read this proof the first time, several years ago. I would be very glad to learn a reference, and (if it is known) the name of the inventor of this nice proof.

Comment: I think its come from DUnford Schwartz Linear OPerators I p.  467

Answer (score 6):

There is a completely elementary and very elegant  proof of the Brower fixed point theorem  based on a beautiful combinatorial result called *Sperner lemma*. For details I recommend  Section 2.3, page 72 of the beautiful book

> V.V. Prasolov: *Elements of
>   Combinatorial and Differential
>   Topology*,  Graduate Studies in
>   Mathematics, vol. 74, Amer. Math.
>   Soc., 2006

The proof    is constructive and it leads to an algorithm for generating a sequence of points converging to a fixed point of the map.   Prasolov  attributes this approach  to

> B. Kuratowski, C. Knaster, C.
>   Mazurkiewicz: *Ein Beweis des Fixpunktsatz fur n-dimensionale Simplexe*,  Funt. Math. **14**(1929),
>   132-137.

**Note** This does not really answer your question.

Comment: It answers the title of the question. :)

Comment: THe KKM paper is freely available at: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm14/fm14111.pdf The proof is not really constructive, one obtains a sequence of completely labeled subsimplices that serve as "almost-fixed-points", which may not be close to any actual fixed point. This sequence is in general not convergent, but one gets a convergent subsequence using compactness and this subsequence converges to an actual fixe-point.

Comment: @Michael  Unfortunately, I cannot read German.  

Comment: There was a brief vogue for using this approach to solve fixed-point problems in economics.  Herb Scarf wrote an elementary introduction that's available at http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/~hes/pub/fixed%20point%20theorems.pdf

Answer (score 5):

In [these notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4540) by Tony Carbery, it is mentioned that a proof along these lines appears in the book *Differential Forms and Applications* by do Carmo, where it is attributed to E. Lima.

Answer (score 5):

Could one of these two be what you're looking for?

1. J. Milnor, Analytic proofs of the “hairy ball theorem” and the Brouwer fixed-point theorem, Amer. Math. Monthly 85 (1978), no. 7, 521–524. MR MR505523 (80m:55001)
2. C. A. Rogers, A less strange version of Milnor’s proof of Brouwer’s fixed-point theorem, Amer. Math. Monthly 87 (1980), no. 7, 525–527. MR MR600910 (82b:55004)

Answer (score 4):

According to Lax in his expository paper [Change of Variables in Multiple Integrals](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589462), Hadamard's original proof of the Brouwer fixed-point theorem from 1910 is based on the determinant formula for change of variables in integrals. The reference he gives is

- J. Hadamard, *Sur quelques applications de l'indice Kronecker*, pp. 437-477, in J. Tannery, *Introduction a la theorie des functions d'une variable*, vol. 2, Paris, 1910.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two further references of proofs of the fixed point theorem that rely on evaluating determinants:

MR0117523 Dunford, Nelson ;  Schwartz, Jacob T.  Linear Operators. I. General Theory.
With the assistance of W. G. Bade and R. G. Bartle. Pure and Applied
 Mathematics, Vol. 7 Interscience Publishers, Inc., New York; Interscience Publishers, Ltd.,
 London  1958 xiv+858 pp. The proof is on page 467.

MR0610487  Kannai, Yakar . An elementary proof of the no-retraction theorem.
 Amer. Math. Monthly  88  (1981),  no. 4, 264--268.

Comment: Whoh!  As a reference for a "simple" proof, he gives an 800-page book!  Please, can someone perhaps provide a sub-interval of the pages...

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, the books has an index with the entry "Brouwer fixed point theorem, proof of, (467)". The proof ends on the top of page 470.

Comment: @Michael: There is no harm in including the page ref -- I agree with @Gerald, even if this is not as hard to look up as it could be...

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting essay on Brouwer's Fixed Point theorem, including a contructive proof, at Kevin Brown's MathPages site http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath262/kmath262.htm

Looking at the home page, I see he has now written a string of books. If his articles are any indication, these books are doubtless excellent and well worth buying.